# Any central limit theorem-like theorem stating distribution of something will be convergent to uniform distribution?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

The central Limit Theorem states that the distribution of the sum of independent random variables (sampled from any population) converges to a normal distribution.

Are there any similar theorems for uniform distributions rather than normal distributions?

Comment: [like this?](http://www.ams.org/journals/tpms/2011-83-00/S0094-9000-2012-00841-7/S0094-9000-2012-00841-7.pdf)